# @click showing ReferenceError: function is not defined with AlpineJS + Livewire + Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

Am totally lost here. I've made multiple applications with Livewire + AlpineJS + Laravel before, but for some reason I cannot get the `@click` functionality working for functions in this app.

I reduced the code to almost nothing and cannot see the issue. Have looked at other apps where I have `@click` working.

```
<div x-data="showAppSettings()">

<div @click="whatever(123)">Click here</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    window.showAppSettings = () => {
        return {
            showNav: false,

            whatever(id)
            {

            }
        };
    }
</script>
```

Upon clicking the click me and triggering the function, I get the error `ReferenceError: whatever is not defined.`

Works just fine if I do something like `@click="alert('hey')"`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was related to including `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>`

That file was not even in use. But either way, the error was being triggered by `app.js` which I realized made no sense since the code was inline.

Upon removing that line, everything works as intended.

Answer (score 2):

It's needed the **defer** attribute to load fine the alpine script:

```html
<script defer src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This one worked for me for the `index not defined` and `range not defined` issue. Cheers!